# Unable to get ResultSet from the MySql DataBase

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I execute the following query on a database containing a table "comm_list" and a field "sr_no" of type "Int" in the table "comm_list", I get the correct resultset

SELECT MAX(sr_no) FROM comm_list;

The above query is to get the max. serial no. so that when I enter a new record, I enter the (serial no. + 1) in the "sr_no" coloum so that I can keep track the no. of records in the database.

I know that it can be done automatically by making the field "sr_no" primary key and make it to auto increement itself whenever a new record is entered but I have another primary key in the table already so I can not make this "sr_no" field as the primary key.

When I execute the above query from my java program to get the max. serial no, the returned resultset doesn't contain any entries. I don't understand where is the problem. I am storing records from the java program to the Database by using jdbc driver.

The following is the code-snippet of my java program.

```
          PreparedStatement getSerial = con.prepareStatement("select max(sr_no) from comm_list"); // "con" is the connection with the database
          getSerial.execute();
          ResultSet rs = getSerial.getResultSet();
          System.out.println(rs.toString()); 
          System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize()); // output - 0
          srNo = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
          System.out.println(srNo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [next](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) method, to move the specified result set to the next row and return whether there *is* a next row:

```
PreparedStatement getSerial = con.prepareStatement("select max(sr_no) from comm_list"); // "con" is the connection with the database
getSerial.execute();
ResultSet rs = getSerial.getResultSet();
if(rs.next()) {
   srNo = rs.getInt(1) + 1;
}
System.out.println(srNo);
```

Answer (score 2):

ResultSets need to be iterated to be used. This is mentioned in the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()). The javadocs are always an invaluable reference for these APIs.

You need to call ResultSet's next() method to get the first result.

There are some getting started examples [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/GetRsData.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement getSerial = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = getSerial.executeQuery("select max(sr_no) from comm_list");
if(rs.next()){
  srNo = rs.getInt(1) + 1;

System.out.println(srNo);
```